# unexpected symbol error while trying to rename columns

Tags: r, dplyr

So I'm new to R and
I am trying to make the columns of this dataset more readable:

[column names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4CO8.png)

with the rename() function from dplyr:

```
  x <- names(data)
  cols <- gsub('\\.', ' ', x)
  
  for (col in ncol(data)) {
    data <- data %>% rename(cols[col] = names(data)[col])
    col
  }
```

but I get an error, which I can't fix with my knowledge or google:

```
Error in source("~/Desktop/r/assignment1/best.R") : 
  ~/Desktop/r/assignment1/best.R:9:45: unexpected '='
8:   for (col in ncol(data)) {
9:     outcome <- data %>% rename(cols[col] =
```

I would be very grateful if someone could tell me where to look for the solution to this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `names(data) <- gsub('\\.', ' ', names(data))`

Comment: It is generally not recommended to have spaces in column names. However, you can simply do `names(data) <- gsub(...)` No loop needed or anything

Comment: The issue is that while in base R you can do selective reassignment of vectors with `vec[ind] <- 1`, that does not work in `dplyr` functions, so `rename(cols[col] = ...)` or `mutate(cols[col] = ...)` or similar will not work. There are workarounds (perhaps `if_else` in some cases), but I believe that the `gsub` workaround here is more succinct.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things about the R way of thinking that you need to get more familiar with:

Learn the difference between names and colnames

Avoid spaces in column names whenever you can, never create them yourself

A for loop should never be your first option, R works on blocks of stuff all at once. 

I actually feel that you shouldn't get help on this question because putting spaces into column names in R is wrong. 

But, if you want to manipulate column names in a dataframe, you can do it directly, but I'm going to change the dots to an underscore, because that's ok.

```
colnames(data) <- gsub("\\\\.", "_", colnames(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use `dplyr::rename_all`. You need to provide a function for renaming. An example would be as follows:

```
mtcars %>% rename_all(~paste0(.,"_renamed"))
```

This will add the `_renamed` postfix to each and every column name. In your case, you can use:

```
df %>% rename_all(~gsub("\\.", " ", .))
```

Keep in mind, though, that spaces in column names is BAD idea.